# Where does $(A\Delta B)\Delta C = ((A\Delta B)\cup C)\cap ((A\Delta B)^c \cup C^c)$ come from?

Tags: logic

I am working with operations and sets, and have been reading about the symmetric difference of AΔB.
The textbook has explained some equivalences of this difference, such as:

$$(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$$

$$(A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c)$$

$$(A\cup B) \setminus (A\cap B)$$

The textbook has also explained satisfactorily why the complement of $A\Delta B$ is $(A^c\cup B)\cap (A\cup B^c)$.

I am reading now the proof of the associativity of the symmetric difference for three elements, and can follow the argument except for the first equality, which seems to have been produced out of the blue (I don't see anything in the textbook previously that verifies it):

$$(A\Delta B)\Delta C = ((A\Delta B)\cup C)\cap ((A\Delta B)^c
\cup C^c)$$

How is this warranted?

Thanks in advance for your ideas.

Comment: Have you tried proving the statement by allowing $x \in (A \Delta B)\Delta C$ and showing $x$ is contained in the right hand side expression?

Comment: I have checked and don't think my question has been answered. My inquiry is not about a proof for the associativity of the triple symmetric difference; what I am asking is about how the equality I've written down is produced.

Comment: Frmo what you wrote further above, the right hand side is the complement of $(A\mathop\Delta B)\mathop\Delta C^\complement$

Comment: Ok, think I got it. Textbook doesn't bother to clarify this first equality, but thanks to wikiproof, I see the missing steps, which require knowing the equivalence that a set difference A ∖ B is equivalent to an intersection with a complement.